# Issue with installing geopandas on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, geopandas

I am new to using python 3.7.0 and have been trying to install geopandas but get an error. I am using a windows 10 computer. I have installed anaconda 3.7 with conda version 3.7.0. I was able to install some other modules like bokeh, pyspark but have an error for geopandas and also geoplot. Could someone help me, please? Thank you in advance!

I used the `conda` command on command prompt run as administrator: 
`conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 geopandas`

I get the following error:

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
typing-3.6.4         | 45 KB     | ############################################################################ | 100%
altair-2.2.2         | 278 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

CondaVerificationError: The package for path.py located at C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\pkgs\path.py-11.0.1-py_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'site-packages/path.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for path.py located at C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\pkgs\path.py-11.0.1-py_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'site-packages/path.py-11.0.1-py2.7.egg-info/PKG-INFO'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for path.py located at C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\pkgs\path.py-11.0.1-py_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'site-packages/path.py-11.0.1-py2.7.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

SafetyError: The package for path.py located at C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\pkgs\path.py-11.0.1-py_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'site-packages/path.py-11.0.1-py2.7.egg-info/installed-files.txt'
has a sha256 mismatch.
  reported sha256: dbd14fc15e9ea05fff49340a8638e465f05a46e64718c3a3c895f933bdc9bd50
  actual sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

CondaVerificationError: The package for path.py located at C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\pkgs\path.py-11.0.1-py_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'site-packages/path.py-11.0.1-py2.7.egg-info/requires.txt'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

CondaVerificationError: The package for path.py located at C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\pkgs\path.py-11.0.1-py_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'site-packages/test_path.py'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::click-plugins-1.0.4-py_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/click_plugins-1.0.4.dist-info/installer'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::click-plugins-1.0.4-py_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/click_plugins-1.0.4.dist-info/metadata'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::click-plugins-1.0.4-py_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/click_plugins-1.0.4.dist-info/record'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::click-plugins-1.0.4-py_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/click_plugins-1.0.4.dist-info/wheel'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::click-plugins-1.0.4-py_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/click_plugins-1.0.4.dist-info/top_level.txt'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::click-plugins-1.0.4-py_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/click_plugins-1.0.4.dist-info/zip-safe'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::click-plugins-1.0.4-py_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/click_plugins/__init__.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::click-plugins-1.0.4-py_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/click_plugins/core.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::cligj-0.4.0-py_1' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/cligj/__init__.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::cligj-0.4.0-py_1' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/cligj/features.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::munch-2.3.2-py_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/munch/__init__.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: The package 'conda-forge/label/gcc7::munch-2.3.2-py_0' cannot be installed due to a
path collision for 'lib/site-packages/munch/python3_compat.py'.
This path already exists in the target prefix, and it won't be removed
by an uninstall action in this transaction. The path is one that conda
doesn't recognize. It may have been created by another package manager.


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults::hdf4-4.2.13-h712560f_2, defaults::hdf5-1.8.18-hcf527f2_1
  path: 'library/copying'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults::hdf4-4.2.13-h712560f_2, defaults::hdf5-1.8.18-hcf527f2_1
  path: 'library/release.txt'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: conda-forge/label/gcc7::jupyter_core-4.4.0-py_0, conda-forge/label/gcc7::jupyter-1.0.0-py_1
  path: 'lib/site-packages/jupyter.py'


ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: conda-forge/label/gcc7::jupyter_core-4.4.0-py_0, conda-forge/label/gcc7::jupyter-1.0.0-py_1
  path: 'lib/site-packages/__pycache__/jupyter.cpython-36.pyc'
```

Comment: is there a reason you are using python 2? or am I misreading

Comment: Could you please edit and format the error as code?

Comment: I tried to use pip install and get an error

Comment: @AlexisDrakopoulos i am using python 3. don't know why it is showing python 2

Comment: @connectyourcharger i do not understand what you mean by formatting the error as code

Comment: Thanks guys. It seems there are issues with python 3.7 and I have solved it  by using a virtual environment with python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

For Windows :

Important! you need to install exact version of pre-requisite libraries, it may not be the latest version as per 23/08/2019

1. From [Python Extension Packages for Windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) download :

   - Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
   - pyproj-2.1.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
   - basemap-1.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
   - Fiona-1.8.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
   - GDAL-2.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
   - Cartopy-0.17.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
2. Install whl file with pip : “pip install download.location.directory\file.whl”

   I am using python 3.7 so I choose cp37 files, if you are using python 2.7 you need to take cp27 files.

   I am using Win-64bit so I choose amd64 files, if you are using Win32 then you need to choose win32 files
3. from same location download and install :

   - geopandas-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

I also install (optional if required)

- descartes-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
- pyepsg-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl